# apex:inputHidden will not rerender but apex:outputpanel does?

Tags: apex, visualforce, actionfunction

On my page I have an `apex:inputhidden` with a value linking to the APEX controller. It looks like this:

```
<apex:inputhidden value="{!conferenceId}" id="hiddenConference" />
```

Then I have an `actionFunction` that calls a method on the back end which will update that `{!conferenceId}` value. This is what the `actionFunction` looks like:

```
<apex:actionfunction name="passAttachmentToController"
                                 action="{!saveConference}"
                                 oncomplete="insertAttachments()"
                                 rerender="hiddenConference, errorMsgTop, errorMsgBottom" />
```

After the `{!conferenceId}` has been updated on the back end the actionFunction will reRender the inputHidden and it should get the new `{!conferenceId}` value. However the inputHidden would not get the new value.

I tried the same code replacing `inputHidden` with an `outputpanel` and it works. Here's the outputpanel:

```
<apex:outputpanel id="hiddenConference">{!conferenceId}</apex:outputpanel>
```

Any ideas why the `outputpanel` updates the `{!conferenceId}` value but the `inputhidden` would not?

**EDIT**

I apologise. Actually the value of the `inputHidden` gets updated.

I was expecting that rerendering the `inputHidden` would update the value in javascript so that I would be able to retrieve the latest value with this line oncomplete:

```
theConferenceId = {!conferenceId};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wrong. The value of the `inputHidden` field had been updating all along. The issue arouse because I had a JavaScript variable linked to the same apex variable that the `inputHidden` was linking to. Like so:

Visual Force:

```
<apex:inputhidden value="{!conferenceId}" id="hiddenConference" />
```

Javascript:

```
var theConferenceId = {!conferenceId};
```

Thus I wrongfully assumed that by updating the inputField on the front end, the JavaScript variable `theConferenceId` would update its value as well(since it's all front end). However this is not the case.

Instead as a solution I linked the JavaScript variable to the inputHidden's value:

```
var theConferenceId = $("[id$='hiddenConference']").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the `<apex:inputHidden>` inside the `<apex:outputPanel>`, it should allow you to refresh and not lose the "Input" abilities.

```
<apex:outputpanel id="hiddenConferencePanel">
  <apex:inputhidden value="{!conferenceId}" id="hiddenConference" />
</apex:outputpanel>
```

There might be other reasons for the problem you're experiencing (I'd like to see more code) but this will get you unstuck.

Comment: Is this an answer?

Comment: I guess it is. It should fix his problem. I'll rephrase.

Comment: It doesn't work. Just tried.

Comment: Just, you know, one sentence and ends in a question mark. Methinks you would flag to delete. :P

Comment: You're right, I would. I rephrased. (Thanks for keeping me in check, Adrian, I do tend to hedge and get lazy sometimes)

Comment: @Arthlete Can you put some more of your code? I suspect there might be something else going on.

Comment: @Arthlete Make sure the rerender in your actionfunction is for the id of the outputpanel, not the inputhidden.

Comment: I updated my question. Please refer to it. It seems that inputHidden was working all along. @AdrianLarson - should I close this or delete it? Could it be useful to somebody else?

Comment: Funny! I wonder the same thing about the question. If you did something to fix your own problem, then add it as an answer and mark it as completed. If you didn't... maybe deleting is not a bad idea. @AdrianLarson, curious to hear your thoughts.

Comment: Post your answer! Even if SFSE just ended up being your rubber duck it might help someone eventually.